# Can't answer my phone call with yosemite

Tags: macos

Whenever a phone call comes in I can answer it on my iPad but not on my macbook(2008) running yosemite.

I also can't call my contacts from my contact list.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handoff only works with fairly recent Macs that support Bluetooth 4.0.

You can check whether Handoff is supported in About this Mac -> System Report...

My 2011 Macbook Pro doesn't have Bluetooth 4.0, so no Handoff for me either.

[image: Screenshot of relevant Bluetooth values for Handoff]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a definitive list of compatible machines yet, but based on reviews I would say your Macbook is too old to support it.

Several sites are claiming that it works on a 2012 model but not 2011.